When i am. trying to run spring intializr using ./mvnw spring-boot:run. it showing the error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.2:run (default-cli) on project initializr: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Please help me with this.

spring-boot:run probably

Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' that means usually you have not defined the spring boot application which means the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication ... without more detailed information it's hard to guess...

In the build section of your pom you need to include the spring-boot-plugin and define the main class.
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
        <configuration>    
            <mainClass>com.yourpackage.YourMainApplicationClassName</mainClass>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

So, if my main application class was MainClass in the package of com.acme, I would set the mainClass property to com.acme.MainClass
